# Can I take the first 15 digits from a field using the API Name in an email template in Salesforce?

Tags: email, api, email-template

I'd like to use a field on my email templates, but not the whole field, just the first 15 digits of the field. Is there a way with using the API Name in the template to limit to which characters are coming through to the email? I'd like to use the REF: email option, and we have a field with it in, but it's got other stuff in that field. Any suggestions or different ways to do that with putting the REF: field into the email?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this template for a case? I am not sure I follow what you are asking...

Comment: No it's being sent from the project. If we have an email come from the project it attaches in the Activity history. If we use the 15 digit project code (basically whats after the salesforce.com/) with a REF: in front of it we can email it with a BCC to sales force and it automatically saves to the activity field in the project view. So I'd like to know a way to take that 15 digit from the web address or the first 15 digits from a field it's in to add it to my email templates.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first 15 *characters* of a field you can normally use the LEFT function inline:

```
{!LEFT(Object.Field, 15)}
```

Edit:

However, it would appear that normal Email Templates don't use those functions.  So instead, if possible, create a custom formula field on your object with the same expression as above.  Then you can reference that custom field inside your email template `{!Object.Custom_15digit__c}`.

Comment: So i've added it to my templates as this and it didn't come through: REF: {!LEFT(pse__Project_ID_Chain__c, 15)} it didn't write anything for the {} field, it was blank.

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked it and it seems that normal email templates don't use those functions.  I edited the answer above.

Comment: Visualforce email templates support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use LEFT(..) in email templates. Here is a simple text email template

```
Here is the Contact id field: {!Contact.Id}

Here is the first 5 chars of the ID field using LEFT function: {!LEFT(Contact.Id,5)}
```

and here is the template rendered in the 'Send an Email' button from a Contact object

```
Here is the Contact id field: 003J000000x0oAP

Here is the first 5 chars of the ID field using LEFT function: 003J0
```

Your issue may be related to whether `pse__Project_ID_Chain__c` is in scope for the object associated with the Workflow / Email Alert. Just because you can write a merge expression for a field doesn't mean that it is referenceable in the context of the email alert.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from a comment you're looking specifically at the pse__Project_Id_Chain__c field, presumably on the pse__Proj__c object.

As others have mentioned you can use formulas to apply a LEFT formula, but since I work on PSA, the app that object/field belong to, I can also say that LEFT-15 on that field is going to return the exact same value as LEFT-15 on just the project records Id. That might be easier to maintain for others since the intended effect is not intertwined with application implementation knowledge.